# Use 6, 5 and 3 to make 57

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Assemble a formula using the numbers $5$, $6$, and $3$ in any order to make $57$. You may use the operations $x + y$, $x - y$, $x \times y$, $x \div y$, $x!$, $\sqrt{x}$, $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}x]{y}$ and $x^y$, as long as all operands are either $3$, $6$, or $5$. Operands may of course also be derived from calculations e.g. $3+(6*5)$. You may also use brackets to clarify order of operations, and you may concatenate two or more of the four digits you start with (such as $6$ and $5$ to make the number $65$) if you wish. You may only use each of the starting digits once and you must use all three of them. I'm afraid that concatenation of numbers from calculations is not permitted, but answers with concatenations which get $57$ will get plus one from me.

Double, triple, etc. factorials (n-druple-factorials), such as $5!! = 5 \times 3 \times 1$ are not allowed, but factorials of factorials are fine, such as $((3)!)! = 6!$. I will upvote answers with double, triple and n-druple-factorials which get $57$, but will not mark them as correct.

A finite number of operations should be used, but answers with an infinite number of operations will get +1 from me...

Comment: Tom, you're posting a lot of these puzzles and they're all basically the same and -- excuse my frankness! -- becoming rather boring. Maybe give them a rest for a while?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan to be honest, some of them are very original, requires good logic deduction. but yes, would be good to give a rest for a while :)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan you could say the same about the large number of Riley riddles. Some people like one kind of puzzle, but not the other, etc. Isn't the time to stop when no-one answers, or there are a lot of very quick correct answers?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - point taken... I will retire from these riddles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possible answer

> $5! - 63 = 57$

Comment: Great job well done

Answer (score 13):

hexomino [beat me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73245), but I have another:

> $\sqrt{5\times6!}-3=57$

Comment: IMO this answer without number concatenation is better.

Comment: @WeatherVane, but both are within the rules, so the sightly earlier answer gets the solution, but both get plus one.

Answer (score 8):

Can I have:

> $56+\sqrt{\sqrt{\dots{3}}}$

Comment: That's a dotty answer. Interesting but is it in the rules?

Comment: @WeatherVane it counts as an infinite number of operations, so gets plus one.

Comment: @tom I see you changed the rules... before this answer was posted.

Comment: @WeatherVane - yes it was an edit a couple of minutes after posting because I figured out this solution, but my screen says this answer was 25 minutes ago and the edit to the question was 33 minutes ago --- that said Jon may well have not seen the edit when he posted the answer. -- Anyway its a good answer and it has my plus one :-)

Comment: @tom your rules were edited about 8 minutes before this question was posted ... although you say it will get an upvote, so I deleted my previous comment. NB I like your number puzzles.

Comment: @WeatherVane - glad you like the number puzzles, but this will be the last for some time - see comments below the question. ... and yes this answer has my upvote  :-)

Comment: You have essentially allowed the floor function applied to the square root of 3.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possibly...

> (5*6*3)-(5*6+3)

Comment: Nice answer, but you have used each digit twice instead of once

Answer (score 1):

> Consider $f = 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 5 * 6 + 3$.  This equals $57$

Comment: Note in the problem statement: *"You may only use each of the starting digits once..."*

Answer (score 1):

> 5! - 63 gives 120 - 63 = 57

I was just looking at possible combinations with factorials.

Comment: Same as the accepted answer!